# Generate distinct client ids in ASP.NET MVC3 when repeating over list of items

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 Razor view that renders editors for a list of customers inside a jQuery UI accordion. At the moment all client-side id's for similar customer properties are the same in the rendered html. For obvious reasons I'd like to change this.

My main view is as follows:

```
<div id="accordionKlanten">
@foreach (var customer in Model.Customers)
{
    <h3><a href="#">@customer.Name</a></h3>
    <div>@{ Html.RenderPartial("CustomerData", customer); }</div>
}
</div>
```

And in my `CustomerData` view (greatly simplified):

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateCustomer", ajaxOptions))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
    <input type="submit" value="Opslaan" />
}
```

This all works perfectly: I can post to my `UpdateCustomer` action method, the model object is bound and a partial view is returned that is rendered back to the client.

But when I have three customers this renders three input fields in my html with `id="Name"`. One of the things that goes wrong is that the `<label for="Name">...</label>` doesn't work since `Name` is not a unique id.

Is there any way to tell tell ASP.NET MVC3 to render distinct `id`'s (while leaving the `name` attributes intact, as these are used to bind to the model)?

For the sake of completeness, here are the two action methods involved:

```
// Returns view that renders editor for each customer.
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var customers = _customerService.GetCustomers();
    return View(new CustomersViewModel { Customers = customers });
}

// Updates a customer and returns a partial view.
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult UpdateCustomer(CustomerDto customer)
{
    // Update customer in database.
    return PartialView("CustomerData", customer);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of writing ugly loops in a view:

```
<div id="accordionKlanten">
@foreach (var customer in Model.Customers)
{
    <h3><a href="#">@customer.Name</a></h3>
    <div>@{ Html.RenderPartial("CustomerData", customer); }</div>
}
</div>
```

use editor templates:

```
<div id="accordionKlanten">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Customers)
</div>
```

and in the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Customer.cshtml`):

```
@model Customer
<h3>
    <a href="#">@customer.Name</a>
</h3>
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstName)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.LastName)
</div>
...
```

Now the `Customer` editor template will be executed automatically for each element of the `Customers` collection property on your model. The only requirement is to respect the naming convention: it should be situated in the `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder and it should be named as the type of the collection item. So for example if the property is `IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel>`, the editor template should be named `CustomerViewModel.cshtml` and obviously be strongly typed to `CustomerViewModel`.

That's all. Now not only that you have cleaned your view but proper names will be used.

Comment: Ok, this works in the sense that unique id's are now generated. However, my model is no longer bound to. I have an update per `Customer` so I also have an (Ajax) form per customer. The correct action method (`UpdateCustomer`) is still called but its `customer` parameter contains no values.

Comment: Reason is that the model binder expects a property with name `Name` but receives a property with name `Customers[0].Name`. Can I fix this without resorting to a custom model binder?

Comment: Yes, have your post action take a parameter type that is the same as your view model.

Comment: I understand that but I'd like to have a post action per customer, not for the entire list of customers. There will never be an update of more than one customer at a time so why waste bandwidth on posting a list of customers?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and can't really see a way around it without plumbing the depths of mvc, which I dont have time to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` loop in your main view.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Customers.Count; i++)
{
    <h3><a href="#">@customer.Name</a></h3>
    <div>@{ Html.RenderPartial("CustomerData", Model.Customers[i]); }</div>
}
```

You will have to adjust this to use a `List<Customer>` or an `Customer[]`.

Comment: No, don't use any loops in a view.

Comment: because since ASP.NET 2.0 there are editor/display templates. See my answer for more details. So loops were only needed in ASP.NET MVC 1.0. Since that time views can be much cleaner.