# ASP.NET MVC: Using EditorFor in a loop - ModelBinding to a single entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I think I may be a little confused :-\

I have a basic scenario whereby I need to render out a list of forms. I have a basic ViewModel that contains a collection of entities. I have an EditorFor template for the entity in question that renders a basic set of inputs.
It looks as follows:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "VehicleLog", new { id = Model[i].id }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "vehicle-update-form std-form", data_ajaxpost = "true", data_refreshcontainer = "#vehicle-ajax-holder" }))
    {
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i])
    <div class="buttons right">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" name="action" class="btn-ok btn" />
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="action" class="btn-warning btn" />
    </div>
    }
}
```

I have a for loop that then dumps out these editor template. So far so good.
My issue is that I wish to use `UpdateModel` in my POST action to update the entity. However, the data being sent to the controller takes the following format:

My incomplete action looks as follows:

```
[HttpPost]

public ActionResult Update(int id, FormCollection data, string action)
{
    var response = new JsonResponse();
    if (action == "Update")
    {
        var v = UnitOfWork.VehicleRepository.GetById(id);
        UpdateModel(v);
    }

    return Json(response);
}
```

My issue is that the EditorFor helpers is (and rightly so) prefixing names with array indexes, eg `[0].name`. As such I am unable to use the UpdateModel method to update an entity.

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Side Note - I am using EditorFor in a loop to prevent the helpers from rendering duplicate id's

Comment: Is FormCollection null on your post action ?

Comment: Nope, it is populated but the names are prefixed with an array index, like [0].name = "john" etc etc. As such UpdateModel cannot identify what post data to use to update the model.

Comment: What kind of Model was bound to your View?

Comment: A standard viewmodel that contains a collection of vehicles, which is what is looped over using the EditorFor

Comment: can you add the vehicle class to your post?

Comment: more importantly, what do you hope to get back to your action method? a List of vehicles or a List of Names?

Comment: If you want model validation, your posted data needs to be bound to a model, i.e. your POST action should accept that model as a param and your form should post the data in a format that will match that model. (The easiest and most obvious way to achieve that is to use the model to render your form fields.)

Comment: I have a viewmodel with a collection. I loop through the collection (code above) and use EditorFor to render a form for each item in the collection. I want the modelbinder to pick up a single entity when the data is posted but the call to editorfor is in a for loop the field names are prefixed with an array index. EditorFor is expecting that all entities will be posted back. I only want to post one back. If I take EditorFor out of a for loop and into a foreach the names are correct, but the ids then clash. It seems rendering a list of FORMS from a collection is a rare use case!

Comment: This question describes a similar setup but is never really answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663674/generate-distinct-client-ids-in-asp-net-mvc3-when-repeating-over-list-of-items

Comment: Please post the code for ViewModel (v) and the HTML that is rendered when the page is displayed.